# Arrow head not showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but the arrow head on the link from the bottom left box to the upper right box does not show up. I want it to be the same as the arrow heads on the other edges. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}        

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}

\tikzstyle{every entity} = []
\tikzstyle{every link} = []
\tikzstyle{smentity} = [rectangle, draw, black, 
                      minimum width=4em, minimum height=2em,
                      every entity]
\tikzstyle{link} = [>=triangle 60, draw, thick, every link]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, every edge/.style={link}]

\node[smentity] (3)  {0001 1000};
\node[smentity] (4) [right= of 3] {1000 0001} edge[<-,dashed] node[above] {\small{01000}} (3);

\node[smentity] (5) [below= of 3] {1000 0000};
\node[smentity] (6) [right= of 5] {1000 0100} edge[->,dashed] (4);

\draw[>=triangle 60,dashed,thick] (5.east) -- ++(0.8,0) node[below,xshift=-0.4cm]{\small{01000}} -| ++(0,2) -- (4.196);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have specified the arrow head but did not select the arrow drawing/direction specification that is `->`. Instead you can directly put `[-triangle 60,dashed,thick]`

Comment: Thank you much; can't believe I made such an elementary mistake, but I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem at all. Do you mind if we close this question as too localized since it's a rather syntax problem rather than a technical one?